# how to make pagination like google only using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to make pagination data like google just using jquery. so when us press button between number 1  and number 6 pagination begin at 1. and when  us press button 7 pagination start at 2 and so forth. someone can help me to make correct algorithm or javascript/jquery program?

Comment: StackOverflow will not write your code for you.

Comment: I have made ​​, but did not running well and the code is very long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created something like this a few years ago (https://github.com/johncobley/jQuery-Paging)

It needs a partial address to which it will add the page number and variables containing the current page number and total quantity of pages (I use a hidden input).

Call it using something like -

```
$(".paging").paging({
    url: "pageurl" + "?page=", //the actual number is added in the plugin
    currentPage: parseInt($("#currentPage").val()),
    pages: $("#pages").val(),
    float: "left"
});
```

`$(".paging")` in this case is an empty div.

It uses CSS classes from jQuery-UI and it appears something like -

[image: First page]

First page

[image: Middle Page]

Middle pages

Comment: thanks for the your information "John C", I already clone your sample, but I can't find user guide  or readme files ?

Comment: I have now added a readme to the project.  I hadn't added a readme previously as it was a personal project